# React/ReactNative static property in function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

In my React Native written TypeScript, I use ReactNavigation. Before I use class component as below

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
   static navigationOptions: any;
   ...
}

// in navigation config
HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {...}
```

With hooks supports, I migrating the HomeScreen to a function component as below

```
function HomeScreen(props:Props) {
  return (...)
}
HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {...} // VS Code error here
```

The thing is I missed `static navigationOptions: any` propery/method, and got error [In VS Code]

> 'navigationOptions' does not exist on type '(props: Props) => Element'

Is there any way to have static property/method in function component? or is there any workaround solution?

Comment: What's your typescript version?

Comment: I am using TS v 3.3

Comment: https://www.reactandtypescript.dev/examples/functional-components#functional-components-with-static-properties

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late. 
Your functional component be like

```
export default function HomeScreen(props){
  return(..)
}
//the following is the static field from class component
HomeScreen.navigationOptions={
 title:'Home',
};
```

I hope this might help someone.

Comment: This seems to be okay for javascript, but got editor complain when using TypeScript. :(

Answer (score 0):

For function components, you can use it like this

```
HomeScreen.navigationOptions = screenProps => ({
    title: 'Home'
})
```

For typescript support

```
interface NavParams {
    id: number;
}
const HomeScreen: NavigationScreenComponent<NavParams> = (props: Props) => {
    return <View><Text>{props.navigation.getParam('id')}</Text></View>
}
HomeScreen.navigationOptions = screenProps => ({
    title: 'Home'
})
```

Comment: Any update for this on the latest version of react-navigation?